# Problem to discuss the differentiability of $f(x)=\sqrt{3x-x^2-2}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

I want to discuss the differentiability of
$$f(x)=\sqrt{3x-x^2-2}.$$

I know that it is defined in $[1,2]$ and here continuous, and surely differentiable in $(1,2)$.

What happens in $x=1$ and $x=2$?

I have tried to compute the limit of incremental ratio.
$$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{\sqrt{(3(1+h)-(1+h)^2-2}}{h}=+\infty$$
BUT when I consider the limit for $h\to 0^-$ I have:
$$\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{\sqrt{(3(1+h)-(1+h)^2-2}}{h}=?$$
I can't compute this since I have under the square root a quantity that goes to $-\infty$, how can I solve this?

Comment: If the limit as $h \to 0+$ is $\infty$ then the function is not differentiable at $1$. Why do you have to look at the limit as $h \to 0-$ ?

Comment: Since I want to understand if x=1 is a point of vertical tangent or a cusp...

Comment: If the left limit were $+\infty$ then in $x=1$ I have a vertical tangent point, while if it were $-\infty$ I would have a cusp

Comment: $f$ is not even defined for $x <1$ so the limit  as $h \to 0-$ does not make sense.

Comment: Oh well I agree...so in $x=1$ I have a vertical tangent point?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is defined on $[a,b]$, then you cannot speak of $$\lim_{h\to 0^-} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$ because, for $h<0$, the expression $f(a+h)$ is not defined. It is not defined because $a+h<a$ and therefore, $a+h\notin [a,b]$.

Applying this to your case, the limit of $\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}$, as $h\to 0^-$, does not exist, because for $h<0$, the expression $f(1+h)$ itself is not defined.